# In desperate need of knowing what font this is

Tags: font-identification

can someone please help id this font? It'd be very very greatly appreciated!

[image: Font id]

Comment: We have some special [requirements for font ID questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/89608). It would be great if you could review these and edit your question to supply the missing information. Thanks.

Comment: If you only want to reproduce the same text, you don't need a font. Draw it in Illustrator or Inkscape. Only examine carefully the dimensions, double carefully the elevations of the horizontal parts of A, E, G and H. You can also outline some nearly same font, for ex. Sweet Sans Light and edit that drawing, if it's not close enough as is.

Comment: What the Font correctly identifies this as [Sweet Sans Extra Light SC](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sweet/sans/extralight-sc/) -- the letters are small capitals (which have slightly different proportions to the uppercase letters).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably Sackers Gothic Light.